# Symfony Form fails to validate multiple uniqueEntity fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem in validating `UniqueEntity` with multiple fields.
I have the following code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_languages", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="IDX_LANGUAGE_CONSTRAINT", columns={"language_id", "app_id"})})
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"languages", "app"})
 */
class AppLanguages extends AbstractEntity
```

When I am trying to post the same language_id and app_id i am getting an `PDOException > PDOException > UniqueConstraintViolationException`

I checked the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath) of symfony I also checked this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491895/900145) but it does not work as it should.
There is also a Validator for done under the namespace `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints` but still this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things :

First, i can see a potential typo issue in what you've shown so far as in the Table constraint annotation you reference to the column "language_id" ( singular ) whereas in your UniqueEntity annotation you reference to the fiel "languages" ( plural ), so maybe try to double check your field / column definition.

The 2 ways you are trying to create your constraint have different purposes :

```
@ORM\UniqueConstraint
```

Is meant to generate schema changes in the database by adding a [SQL UNIQUE constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp). Doing this enforces your database engine to check every entry in the said table and generate an error ( Exemple : "error #1062" for MySQL ) which can be relayed by the PDO into your PHP output.

```
@UniqueEntity
```

On the other hand, UniqueEntity is meant to validate your PHP Entity ( doing a $form->isValid() for exemple ) by firing a SELECT statement against your database and checking if there are any results similar to the submitted values.

Point is, reading carrefully and understanding the exception you are getting back will help you understand which constraint exactly causes the issue and finding the cause (is it an issue with the datas already in base ?).

Moreover, depending on what you need to do, you may not need to include the 2 constraints, and only use the @UniqueEntity or the @UniqueConstraint.

EDIT :

You could try to use the [repositorymethod](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#repositorymethod) option to enforce the request used for validation by creating your own repository method.

Hope this helps

Comment: well the problem is if I am using only UniqueEntity for those 2 fields it passes the validation. So this is why I added just for safety for now the constraint and then use a try catch to set the form error (I know it's not elegant but it works ..) I already have data in the database. Imagine i have app_id = 1 lang_id = 1 -> saved app_id = 1 lang_id = 2 -> saved lang_id = 2 -> fails. If the form validation does not work then the sql constraint should do the trick for now.

Comment: @HerrNentu' My bad then i missunderstood the issue ( thought you didn't catch why you were getting a PDO Exception while it's the other way around ) .I ended up finding this closed bugreport  which has an interesting conclusion that may explain your issue : [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6727)