# UniqueEntity contraint not working

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the unique entity contraint on my user entity but somehow it doesn't work. I still get the error message of a duplicate key.

This is my User entity:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email", "username"}
 * )
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    public $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    public $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    public $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserDetails", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $userDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Assignment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $assignments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->assignments = new ArrayCollection();
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }


    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt and argon2i algorithms don't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }


    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        if (!in_array('ROLE_USER', $roles)) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }
        return $roles;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function getUserDetails(): ?UserDetails
    {
        return $this->userDetails;
    }

    public function setUserDetails(UserDetails $userDetails): self
    {
        $this->userDetails = $userDetails;

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($this !== $userDetails->getUser()) {
            $userDetails->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Assignment[]
     */
    public function getAssignments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->assignments;
    }

    public function addAssignment(Assignment $assignment): self
    {
        if (!$this->assignments->contains($assignment)) {
            $this->assignments[] = $assignment;
            $assignment->addUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAssignment(Assignment $assignment): self
    {
        if ($this->assignments->contains($assignment)) {
            $this->assignments->removeElement($assignment);
            $assignment->removeUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I get the following error message when I submit the form:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Users (username, password, email, is_active, roles) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["sanderbakker", "$2y$13$evlC1NcG9BIdgeBRuBqCKu4uqt4Edsp24SEUIiYF3vg6rp0tEhHdm", "sander@crmfabriek.nl", 1, "a:1:{i:0;s:10:\"ROLE_ADMIN\";}"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sanderbakker' for key 'UNIQ_D5428AEDF85E0677'

This error won't appear if I only use one attribute as contraint. For example only the username attribute or the email attribute

Comment: Yep.  Add two constraints.  One for username and one for email.  The way you have it now, the constraint is saying that the combination of username and email must be unique.

Comment: Same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491675/symfony2-uniqueentity-multiple-fields-false-positive-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how "UniqueEntity" constraint works.
It adds a control on the combination of username and email, if you're trying to insert a record that contains both email and username already present in your table the orm raises an exception.
You can check with a select if the combination already exists before the flush or, if you want, to handle that you can insert your flush operation into a try/catch block like this

```
try {
    $em->flush();
} catch (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    // handle it here maybe returning an error to the UI
}
```